# Getting the latest NVIDIA graphics driver through Software & Updates

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, graphics

Is there a way I can install the latest NVIDIA driver https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/ using the Software & Updates GUI rather than directly? In my experience manually installing the NVIDIA graphics driver comes at the cost of more instability, but the 495 proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver does not support vulkan 1.3, which I need at the moment.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your GPU model? Did you tried to open Software & Updates, drivers tab?

Comment: 21.10, GTX 1070, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following commands to remove the existing nvidia proprietary graphics driver packages.

```
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

Run the following commands in all currently supported versions of
Ubuntu to install the nvidia-driver-510 package from [ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510 -y  
sudo reboot
```

As of 2024 the version of the latest proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa has been updated from 510 to 550, so replace `nvidia-driver-510` with `nvidia-driver-550` in the above code block. This method enables nvidia-driver-550 as an upgrade to the existing nvidia-driver-535 package and other similar nvidia-driver packages from the default Ubuntu 22.04 repositories.

After logging back in, run the following command to confirm the NVIDIA drivers are installed.

```
nvidia-smi
```

Comment: If you already have a nVidia driver installed, you need to first purge all old drivers. `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`